# MySQL Workbench - Fix Index Names Warning

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a new client that is running a Symfony application with 170 or so MySQL tables. He recently updated his MySQL Workbench to the latest revision and is now getting a warning pop-up when he launched the application

FIX INDEX NAMES
Index names identical to FK names were found in the model, which is not allowed for MySQL5.5 and later. Would you like to rename the indexes?

I am not a DBA but I understand that the index and primary key names are clashing. What are the implications of renaming these indexes vs. just ignoring?

The Symfony app he is running uses the Doctrine ORM, would any queries or the model need to be updated should the indexes be renamed?

Using the InnoDB engine

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench checks at opening a model if there are any duplicate index names and offers to rename them to be unique. Letting it doing this has not bad side effect. In fact it is even necessary to be able to apply the model to a server. Otherwise the server will refuse to create tables that contain an index with a name that was already taken.

So in short: it's a good idea to let Workbench fix this bug (since duplicate key names are nothing but a bug).